# innerHtml doesn't work with Ionic tags

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with Ionic 3 and Angular 4. I know that `innerHtml` doesn't work with ionic tags like `ion-img`, etc.

I searched in Google and I found that I can use `ng-bind-html` but this tag doesn't work in Ionic 3, I get an error that it doesn't exist.

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ng-bind-html' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-card-content'
```

So what is the best way to do that?

Example. I have this variable

```
htmlcode = '<ion-item><ion-avatar item-left><img src="assets/images/01.png" alt="Icon"/></ion-avatar></ion-item>'
```

And when I use innerhtml the ionic tags disappear because are not HTML code. But the HTML tag, in this case the img tag, works perflecty so.. how can I insert in ionic dinamically ionic tags..

Comment: [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) is for AngularJS (1.x) not Angular (2+).

Comment: So? What can I do??

Comment: Well it's not clear what you're trying to *do*; perhaps you could give some more context, a [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think is self explanatory.. but I update the question.. Ionic tags, doesnt work  with innerhtml..

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473910/how-to-dynamically-add-innerhtml-with-angular-2-components?

Comment: Yeah. but my var can have very different "ionic html" structure.. so, is not posible to generate a component.. I can not  use a template..