# Angular Material tags are not rendering as HTML tags when inserted using innerHTML property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to display below code which is being inserted using **"innerHTML"** property in Angular 4.

```html
<div class="type-face">
    <md-card class="mat-card">
        <md-card-content class="mat-card-content">
            <p><strong>Ab</strong> Maison Neue Demi</p>
        </md-card-content>
        <div class="card-footer">Sans-Serif</div>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

But, the output which is displaying in the browser is just plain HTML.

```html
<div class="type-face">
    <p><strong>Ab</strong> Maison Neue Demi</p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="card-footer">Sans-Serif</div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can also render Angular Material tags along with HTML tags?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490169/5621827)

Answer (score 0):

You can't render components using the `innerHTML` property. Instead, use [`Portal`](https://material2-docs-dev.firebaseapp.com/cdk/portal/overview) which is similar to [dynamic components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

1. Import `PortalModule` from `@angular/cdk/portal` to your app's module:

   ```ts
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
   import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
   // Other module imports go here

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           BrowserModule,
           BrowserAnimationsModule,
           PortalModule,
           // Other modules go here
       ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
2. Place this HTML in a component and import it in your app's module as well as `entryComponents` array.

   `exampletemplate.component.html`:

   ```
   <div class="type-face">
       <md-card class="mat-card">
           <md-card-content class="mat-card-content">
               <p><strong>Ab</strong> Maison Neue Demi</p>
           </md-card-content>
           <div class="card-footer">Sans-Serif</div>
       </md-card>
   </div>
   ```

   `exampletemplate.component.ts`

   ```ts
   @Component({
       selector: 'template-example',
       templateUrl: './exampletemplate.component.html'
   })
   export class ExampleTemplateComponent {}
   ```

   `app.module.ts`

   ```ts
   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
           ExampleTemplateComponent
       ],
       entryComponents: [
           ExampleTemplateComponent
       ]
   })
   ```
3. Add an `ng-template` directive to wherever you would like your dynamic content to be. Add an attribute `[cdkPortalHost]` and bind it to an attribute (in this example, `exampleHost`) in your component typescript.

   ```html
   <ng-template [cdkPortalHost]="exampleHost"></ng-template>
   ```
4. In your component typescript, initialize the portal host to use type `ComponentPortal<any>` which is also available at `@angular/cdk/portal` and possibly add a function to set it:

   ```ts
   import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
   import { ExampleTemplateComponent } from './path/to/exampletemplate.component';
   // Other imports go here

   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
       exampleHost: ComponentPortal<any>;
       ngOnInit() {
           this.exampleHost = new ComponentPortal(ExampleTemplateComponent);
       }
   }
   ```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-html-angular-so)