# How to render a for loop in innerHtml Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Hi am working on an angular 2 project and i have a material dialog box. Am passing the data to the dialog box from my parent as below:

```js
let infoDialog = this.mdDialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
                        'data': {
                            'type': 'error',
                            'content': `<ng-container *ngFor="let x of data.status.message">
                            <label [innerHtml]="x"></label>
                          </ng-container>`,
                        },
                        'disableClose': true
                    });
```

and in my dialog I have the placeholder like below

```html
<div mat-dialog-content class="u-margin-top-24" [class.no-margin]="type === 'error'">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 content">
          <div [innerHtml]="content | translate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Some how the content is not displaying in the dialog. Any idea whats happening guys?

Comment: Read it [How to dynamically add innerHTML with angular 2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473910/how-to-dynamically-add-innerhtml-with-angular-2-components)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

instead of `content` use `data.content`

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="u-margin-top-24" [class.no-margin]="type === 'error'">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 content">
          <div [innerHtml]="data.content | translate"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```