# convert text to html angular2 Custom Pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe

I am learning Angular 2 and now I am stuck on a custom pipe. I made a domain find pipe

```
export class FindDomain implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: string, args: string[]): any {
    if (!value) return value;

    var regex = /((http|ftp|https):\/\/)*([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+)*)[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.+([a-z]{10}|nl|be|biz|com|net)+)+)([\w.@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-]*)?/g;
    return value.replace(regex, function(txt) {           
        return "<a href='+txt + "'>"+ txt + "</a>";
    });
  }
}
```

It's working fine, but now it's returning text ( ) not a clickable html element. 
I am using

> < h2 >{{ gift.naam | findDomain }}< /h2 >

after some searching on internet, I found

> < h2 [innerHtml]="{{ gift.naam | findDomain }}">< /h2 >

The first option returns plain text and the second option big errors

> *Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ gift.naam | findDomain }}]*

I think it must be a simple solution, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: You can't use `[]` and `{{}}` together. Either one or the other, but not both. The 2nd option is just invalid.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid :(. But thanks. That's it.