# angular2 loading base64 gives error WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value

Tags: angular, base64

I hit my api and get back a base64 string which I want to populate as an image on angular2 frontend.

This is how my service looks like:

```
private myUrl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/gallery/'

constructor(private http: Http){

}

fetchGallery(id: number){


    return this.http.get( this.myUrl + id + '/', {withCredentials: true})
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())

}
```

I call this service through my component:

```
fetchGallery(id: number){

        this.galleryService.fetchGallery(id)
        .then( 
            response => {
                this.gallery = response;
            });
    }
```

And on HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of gallery">
  <img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+image">
</div>
```

As a response I get back:

```
["data:image/jpg;base64,--base64 string--"]
```

It gives me error saying:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value
```

Where and what should I correct?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868