# Set style dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular

I have following markup

```
<tr *ngFor='let activity of pagedWorkflowActivities' style="background-color:{{activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green'}}">
.
.
.
.
</tr>
```

As it says, if `activity.status` field is pending then make background color red otherwise green. But it doesn't work. After inspecting I found it renders it like

```
<tr ng-reflect-style="unsafe">
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
[style.background-color]="activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green'"
```

or

```
[ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green' }"
```

For your rendering result see also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: There are different ways and the alternatives might be more convenient in other situations.

Comment: I have seen this error message but I don't remember what caused it. A suggestion. Don't use method calls in view bindings (only event handlers) because this method will be called every time change detection runs. Also if the method returns a new object instance with every call like `return { a: b };`,   you'll get an exception from Angulars change detection. Rather assign the result of the method call to a property and bind to that property, or if you still want to use a method, cache the result and return the cached instance in case the parameters haven't changed.

Comment: "new question" - I guess this would be a good idea. I guess it needs more details (code) to diagnose.

Comment: what is the best way to do this programmatically, from .ts class?

Answer (score 4):

**Try this one:**

```
[ngStyle]="{'border': user?.keyResults.percentage > 50 ? '3px solid green' : '3px solid red' }"
```

Answer (score 1):

`bind-` prefix alternative can be used also as below

```
bind-style.background-color="activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green'"
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over simply `[style.background-color]`?