# When do we user styles and ngstyle in angular?

Tags: angular

I am often confused between styles and ngstyles of angular 2. 
When we should use styles and when we should user ngstyle in angular? 
What is the purpose of both?
Any real time example for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just depends if you have more than one style to add.

```
[style.background-color]="activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green'"
```

and

```
[ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': activity.status == 'Pending' ? 'red' : 'green';''margin': functionExample()}"
```

And this is the same with `[ngClass]` and `[class.your-class]`

This the question here: [Set style dynamically in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular2)