# How to bind a object value to ngStyle?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to change the color of a button using `ngStyle` and the array of object return from my server side.
From my server, I am getting an array of objects

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "User 1",
  designation: "Software Developer",
  isActive: "Yes",
  IsActiveStyle: "blue"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "User 2",
  designation: "Software Developer",
  isActive: "Yes",
  IsActiveStyle: "blue"
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "User 3",
  designation: "Software Tester",
  isActive: "No",
  IsActiveStyle: "red"
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: "User 4",
  designation: "Tester",
  isActive: "Yes",
  IsActiveStyle: "blue"
}
```

I am trying to bind, my `IsActiveStyle` to `ngStyle` with the following code

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'background-color':item.IsActiveStyle}">{{item.isActive}}</button>
```

but unable to understand, why it is not changing the color of my button.

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: use `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular2

Comment: @sriharsha_bhat the examples [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) use kebab-style syntax

Comment: [Works for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56rasy)

Comment: it's working can you share html template code

Comment: can you share a working example?