# How to allow user to change font size in an angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to make user change the font size and family in an angular application, need to have different settings for every user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set style dynamically in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular2)

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: You can use computed CSS properties

Comment: you could use **ngStyle** https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a global class like `fs-11, fs-12, fs-13, fs-14` By global class I mean something that is present at the top level DOM element. You can use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for that. An than in your `style.scss` just do it like this.

```
.fs-11 {
  span,p {
    font-size: 11;
  }
}
.fs-12 {
  span,p {
    font-size: 12;
  }
}
```

Then you can use a `Subject` from `rxjs/operator` to subscribe to event that font size has changed. [This is a good tutorial for that.](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1)

Then when ever the value of the font-size is passed through above Subject and whenever there is a change it'll get you the latest value.

I'll come up with a stackblitz example if I get some time till than you can work with the idea I've posted.

Here is a working StackBlitz demo I made let me know if you have any issue with that. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qabs5k

Answer (score 0):

You will have one global component where is everyone it's child for example `app-component`. So, add users chosen font there and every child will inherit it, for example

```
@Component({
  selector: "app",
  template: `
    //YOUR PRESENTATION HERE
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding("style.font.size")
  get userFontSize() {
    return _userFontSize;
  }

  @HostBinding("style.font.family")
  get userFontFamily() {
    return _userFontFamily;
  }

  _userFontFamily: string;
  _userFontSize: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    //Whenever you apply new value either fontsize or fontfamily, the value will be updated
    this._userFontSize = "20px";
    this._userFontFamily = "Sylfaen";
  }
}
```

rendered dom will be like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <app style="font-size:20px;font-family:sylfaen">
        </app>
    </body>
</html>
```