# how to add a class dynamically?

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular7, ng-class

I've been programming in Angular for a short time and I got stuck on the button design. 
I have already implemented them with an ngIf, appearing and disappearing dynamically depending on whether they were available or not.
The thing is that I find it a bit complicated and I wanted to take advantage of the same logic to have them always displayed on screen but add color depending on the same condition that I used before.
I have tried to implement the use of ngClass but it is clear that something is wrong because it does not work.
here my html:

```
<div *ngIf="mainFlowchartInstance.eisChartData.value" class="temp_zoom-actions">
      <div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons == 'zoomButtons.reset'}" class="center" (click)="zoomReset()"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></div>
      <div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons == 'zoomButtons.out'}" class="zoom-out" (click)="zoomOut()"><i class="icon-search-minus"></i></div>
      <div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons == 'zoomButtons.in'}" class="zoom-in" (click)="zoomIn()"><i class="icon-search-plus"></i></div>
</div>
```

and here my ts:

```
  public zoomButtons = {
    in: false,
    out: true,
    reset: false
  };


  setZoomButtonsState() {
    this.zoomButtons.out = !!this.currentZoomPosition;
    this.zoomButtons.in = this.zoomButtons.reset = !(this.currentZoomPosition === this.rangeZooms.length - 1);
  }
```

Someone to make me see my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the **'** in the condition: `{'orangeText' : zoomButtons == zoomButtons.reset}`. else Angular expect a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set style dynamically in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it in this way (check if `zoomButtons.reset` or `zoomButtons.out` or `zoomButtons.in` are `true` or `false`, then apply class `orangeText`):

```
<div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons.reset}" 
  class="center" (click)="zoomReset()">
  <i class="icon-refresh"></i>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons.out}" 
  class="zoom-out" (click)="zoomOut()">
  <i class="icon-search-minus"></i>
</div>
<div [ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons.in}" 
  class="zoom-in" (click)="zoomIn()">
  <i class="icon-search-plus"></i>
</div>
```

Class `orangeText` will apply if it gets `true` after `:`, like in this example  from angular [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description):

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">
```

and in this place:

```
[ngClass]="{'orangeText' : zoomButtons.reset}"
```

`zoomButtons.reset` without single quotation marks will be treated as a variable, so will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: thank u , works perfect!