# How to apply a click listener to an element in Angular and properly display dynamic HTML content that includes style tags and id?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am facing a problem where I need to display dynamic HTML content that includes a dynamic background-color value, as part of a string that contains style tags and an id. Here's an example:

```
this is <mark id="12345" style="background-color: red">my marked</mark> text?
```

I am using the innerHTML property to display the content in my Angular app, but I am having issues with applying styles and adding a click listener in the same time.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div [innerHTML]="myString"></div>
```

**TS**

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const markTags = this.description.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mark');
      markTags.forEach((tag: HTMLElement) => {
        tag.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        });
      });
    }, 100);
  }
```

In this case the click listener works, but the style is not applied.

When I use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` to sanitize the HTML content, the styles do apply, but the click listener does not work.

```
   private readonly _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,  
   return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(TASK.description);
```

How can i apply both the click listeners and the styles to this HTML content?

I would like also to mention that the app is inside a closed network so the security risks are minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the html like this:

```
<div #myDiv [innerHTML]="descr"></div>
```

and added some variables:

```
description =
    'this is <mark id="12345" style="background-color: red">my marked</mark> text?';
  descr: SafeHtml;
  @ViewChild('myDiv', { static: true }) myDiv: ElementRef;
```

and modified the methods like this:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.descr = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.description);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const markTags = this.myDiv.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mark');
    markTags.forEach((tag: HTMLElement) => {
      tag.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        alert('mark clicked');
      });
    });
  }
```

Here is a functioning stacklbitz too: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5urtkj?file=src/main.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Its simpler. Angular has some events directives built in, one of them is `(click)="isClicked($event)"` [look this doc](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

And about styles, you can look for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676203/set-style-dynamically-in-angular).