# Adding line breaks when using interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have some html for an alert message box. Using interpolation, I can re-use the same html to show multiple different alert messages. It looks like this: `<p>{{ myAlertMessage }}</p>`

Now I want to show a longer alert message containing line breaks. However, I cannot seem to modify the interpolated component property (which is a string) in any way which will introduce line breaks.

For example, using `</br>`, or spacing the text across several lines in the component code (contained in either parentheses or back ticks), or the new line code (`&#13;`). None of these work to produce a line break in the text when the alert message is shown.

I would prefer not to have to add further property bindings just to cater for this particular use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/ ...this can be helpful

Comment: It would seem any html sequences are being escaped automatically, is there any way for you to turn that feature off? I'm not to familiar with typescript or angular so just a suggestion.

Comment: Does adding a \n not work?  "System Alert\nSomething has happened"

Comment: @Call_Back_Function I tried that and no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution, for Angular v2.1.1 at least, is to use `[innerHTML]="myAlertMessage"`. It isn't necessary to use "bypassSecurityTrustHtml" for line breaks or lists to work.

Answer (score 7):

Just use

```
<span [innerHTML]="myAlertMessage"></span>
```

the innerHTML property will interpret your html code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pipe like

```
import { Pipe, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafeHtml {
  constructor(private sanitizer:Sanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
<span [innerHTML]="myAlertMessage | safe"></span>
```

where `myAlertMessage` can contain `<br>` or `<p>`

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: It's not compatible with IE. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's not enough information. I'd suggest you create a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\n` in your `myAlertMessage` text.
Something like that: `"\n Some alert text \n Newline of the alert text";`

And use a `<pre>` html tag in your component HTML file like that:

```
<div>
  <p><pre>{{ myAlertMessage }}</pre></p>
</div>
```