# Angular 5 text expansion include HTML

Tags: angular5

I have a simple text expansion in my template like so:

```
<td>{{ someMethodHere() }}</td>
```

and I want the string that's returned from `someMethodHere` to include a line-break.  I've tried including both `\n` and `<br/>` in the returned string but neither is actually evaluated in the resulting HTML.

What's the trick to this?

Comment: you would need to set the `.innerHTML` of the `<td>` tag

Comment: That works, thanks.  I added n `[innerHTML]` binding to the `td` tag.  If you want to show that in an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding line breaks when using interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746142/adding-line-breaks-when-using-interpolation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use html markup, you need to set the `innerHTML`. Something like the following would work using your placeholder function:

`<td [innerHTML]="someMethodHere()"></td>`