# How to render dynamic components in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need render button but it doesn't work
I use ionic 2

> home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
      content:string ='<button ion-button color="light">Light</button>';
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }
    }
```

> home.html

```
<ion-content>
<ion-card>
    {{content}}
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

[image: This result]

Comment: May I ask what do you need to accomplish? Because maybe there's another way to do it instead of using the `DomSanitizer` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Change code to `<ion-card [innerHtml]="content"></ion-card>`

`{{content}}` will just print out the value as a string. But the `innerHtml` will actually use the raw html data

Comment: "innerHtml" work fine with string(h1,p,div) if use <button></button> it doesn't work I don't know why ><

Comment: Take a look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868