# Converting string to html element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working angular2 project as well as I'm coding with typescript. I have a service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/component.template.html'
})

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(public myServie: MyService) {
        this.myServie.get().then((data: any) => {
            // data has html content
        });
    }
}
```

Service result is like this:

```
a ='<p>
 <a class="link1" href="#p1">link 1</a>
 <a class="link2" href="#p2">link 2</a>
 <a class="link3" href="#p3">link 3</a>
</p>'
```

How can I search in this content, find element with class="link1" and replace its href? I don't want to use JQuery or something like that.

Comment: Does data contain `a`?

Comment: Not sure what angular or typescript allows... but if you don't want to include more libraries, you always have the option of using vanilla JS.  Something like this should work fine: document.getElementsByClassName("link1").href="website.com";

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: do you compile this ? I mean, does this goes into DOM, if it's not , you'd need to use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div [innerHtml]="data | safeHtml"></div>
```

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

```
constructor(
    private elRef:ElementRef, 
    public myServie: MyService,
    private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.myServie.get().then((data: any) => {
        this.data = data;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // to ensure the DOM is updated
        if(this.isViewInitialized) {
          this.updateHrefs();
        }
    });
}

isViewInitialized = false;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.isViewInitialized = true;
  if(this.data) {
    this.updateHrefs();
  }
}

updateHrefs() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p > a').forEach((e) => { e.href = 'newHref'; });

}
```

Comment: Good idea. but its not working. I'm getting data form remote rest api. So ngAfterViewInit fires before data bound (in constructor).

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. That makes it a bit more complicated. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: tnx. It worked. Can i ask why have u used 'a > a'? I'm using 'a'.

Comment: Ups, I meant `'p > a'` but if there are no other `<a>` then jsut `'a'` will work as well.