# unable bind button control to div tag using [innerHTML] in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to bind dynamically generated markup  to a div tag using [innerHTML] .
I'm successful in binding markup that consists of Unorderd list. But when I try to bind markup that has button control , it is getting encoded and there by removes the button.

```
<div [innerHTML]="Element.Markup"></div>
```

the Element.Markup looks like

```
<button type='button'>Click Here</button> Some Text...
```

When i run the app, the button tags are removed and the web page display plain text like

```
Click Here Some Text..
```

Is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: The Sanitizer service strips security related tags and styles. You need to mark the HTML as trusted.

Comment: Thanks. please let me know how to mark html as trusted .

Comment: See the linked answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax

Comment: Hey @GünterZöchbauer, thank you so much. your post fixed my issue