# SVG is not loaded with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, svg, typescript

I'm making a site and will place inline with my HTML, SVG pictures. I've made a component with Angular 2 but the SVG icons will not load. It's showing me this:

[image]

Below and on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4fur9gb/1/) you could find my code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of achievements; let i = index" class="achievementscontainer">
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{item.description.replace('%d', item.next)}}</p>
    <div [innerHTML]="item.image" [class]="item.status"></div>
    <p class="bold">Progress till next achievement:</p>
    <p><span>{{item.progress}}</span>/<span>{{item.next}}</span></p>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    templateUrl: "./profile.component.html"
})
export class ProfileComponent {
    achievements = [
        { 
            image: `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path class="st0" d="M194.5,101.5c10.3-10.8,16.6-25.4,16.6-41.4C211.1,26.9,184.2,0,151,0C117.9,0,91,26.9,91,60.1 c0,15.8,6.1,30.2,16.1,40.9c-33.7,10.4-58.4,41.8-58.4,78.8v84.8c0,19.4,15.9,35.3,35.3,35.3h129.6c20.7,0,37.7-17,37.7-37.7v-82.5 C251.3,143.4,227.4,112.4,194.5,101.5z"/>
                    </svg>`, 
            name: "Follower", 
            description: "Followed %d people", 
            progress: 6,
            next: 35,
            status: "brons"
        }, { 
            image: `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path class="st0" d="M263.1,218.1l2.6-4.5l13.5,7.8c11.4-20.5,18.1-43.9,18.6-68.9H282v-5.2h15.7c-0.4-25-7-48.5-18.4-69l-13.7,7.9 l-2.6-4.5l13.7-7.9c-12.4-20.7-29.8-38.1-50.5-50.5l-7.9,13.7l-4.5-2.6l7.9-13.7c-20.5-11.4-44-18-69-18.4v15.7h-5.2V2.4 c-25,0.5-48.4,7.1-68.9,18.6l7.8,13.5L82,37.1l-7.8-13.5C53.6,36,36.3,53.4,23.9,74.1l13.4,7.7l-2.6,4.5l-13.4-7.7 C10,99,3.4,122.4,3,147.4h15.3v5.2H3c0.5,24.9,7.1,48.3,18.5,68.7l13.2-7.6l2.6,4.5l-13.2,7.6c12.4,20.6,29.7,37.9,50.3,50.3 l7.6-13.2l4.5,2.6l-7.6,13.2c20.4,11.3,43.8,18,68.7,18.4v-15.3h5.2v15.3c24.9-0.4,48.4-7,68.8-18.3l-7.7-13.3l4.5-2.6l7.7,13.3 c20.7-12.4,38-29.7,50.5-50.3L263.1,218.1z M228.1,55.1l-66.9,92.5c0.4,2.9,0,5.8-1.3,8.5l47.1,71.5c0.9,1.3,0.5,3.1-0.8,4l-8.4,5.6 c-1.3,0.8-3,0.5-3.8-0.8L146,163.7c-3.1-0.3-6.2-1.6-8.6-4c-5.5-5.5-5.5-14.3,0-19.8c3.6-3.6,8.6-4.8,13.2-3.7l65.1-90 c0.9-1.2,2.5-1.5,3.7-0.6l7.9,5.7C228.7,52.1,229,53.9,228.1,55.1z"/>
                    </svg>`, 
            name: "Tracker", 
            description: "Tracked %d series", 
            progress: 6,
            next: 20,
            status: "silver"
        }, { 
            image: `<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <path class="st0" d="M263.1,218.1l2.6-4.5l13.5,7.8c11.4-20.5,18.1-43.9,18.6-68.9H282v-5.2h15.7c-0.4-25-7-48.5-18.4-69l-13.7,7.9 l-2.6-4.5l13.7-7.9c-12.4-20.7-29.8-38.1-50.5-50.5l-7.9,13.7l-4.5-2.6l7.9-13.7c-20.5-11.4-44-18-69-18.4v15.7h-5.2V2.4 c-25,0.5-48.4,7.1-68.9,18.6l7.8,13.5L82,37.1l-7.8-13.5C53.6,36,36.3,53.4,23.9,74.1l13.4,7.7l-2.6,4.5l-13.4-7.7 c10,99,3.4,122.4,3,147.4h15.3v5.2H3c0.5,24.9,7.1,48.3,18.5,68.7l13.2-7.6l2.6,4.5l-13.2,7.6c12.4,20.6,29.7,37.9,50.3,50.3 l7.6-13.2l4.5,2.6l-7.6,13.2c20.4,11.3,43.8,18,68.7,18.4v-15.3h5.2v15.3c24.9-0.4,48.4-7,68.8-18.3l-7.7-13.3l4.5-2.6l7.7,13.3 c20.7-12.4,38-29.7,50.5-50.3L263.1,218.1z M228.1,55.1l-66.9,92.5c0.4,2.9,0,5.8-1.3,8.5l47.1,71.5c0.9,1.3,0.5,3.1-0.8,4l-8.4,5.6 c-1.3,0.8-3,0.5-3.8-0.8L146,163.7c-3.1-0.3-6.2-1.6-8.6-4c-5.5-5.5-5.5-14.3,0-19.8c3.6-3.6,8.6-4.8,13.2-3.7l65.1-90 c0.9-1.2,2.5-1.5,3.7-0.6l7.9,5.7C228.7,52.1,229,53.9,228.1,55.1z"/>
                    </svg>`, 
            name: "Watcher", 
            description: "Watched %d hours", 
            progress: 6,
            next: 50,
            status: "gold"
        }
    ];
}
```

The output in the browser is this:

```html
<div _ngcontent-ejj-7="" class="achievementscontainer"> <!-- three thimes -->
    <h3 _ngcontent-ejj-7="">Follower</h3>
    <p _ngcontent-ejj-7="">Followed 35 people</p>
    <div _ngcontent-ejj-7="" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="&amp;#10;                        &amp;#10;                    " ng-reflect-class-name="brons" class="brons"></div>
    <p _ngcontent-ejj-7="" class="bold">Progress till next achievement:</p>
    <p _ngcontent-ejj-7=""><span _ngcontent-ejj-7="">6</span>/<span _ngcontent-ejj-7="">35</span></p>
</div>
```

How comes it that the SVG is not rendering in the browser with Angular 2?

**P.S. 1:** If you will run the code, you can check out this GitHub project: [WatchFriends/Web](https://github.com/WatchFriends/Web/tree/dev-profile/frontend/app/profile) on branch `dev-profile` in folder `./frontend/app/profile`. The url is http://localhost:4200/profile.

**P.S. 2:** Happy 2017 and may your wish come true :)

Comment: Happy 2017. You need to use `DOMSanitizer` to load svg from `ts` code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I've found the solution to my problem. I've add constructor and methode form code below to my class:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

and in my HTML I use

```
<div [innerHTML]="transform(item.image)" [class]="item.status"></div>
```

in stead of

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.image" [class]="item.status"></div>
```

Thanks to @micronyks and @GünterZöchbauer for there comments.