# Convert String to HTML code in Angular 2

Tags: html, function, angular

I have a problem to convert string to HTML code. I just want to convert &#160 to HTML code, This value set from variable String. this is my code

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.submitButtonText = 'Save';
    this.spaceMenu= '&#160;&#160;&#160;';
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        'id': [],
        'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3)])],
        'description': []
    });
    this.name = this.form.controls['name'];
    this.description = this.form.controls['description'];
    this.service.getMenuGroup()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.setMenuGroup(data['menuGroup']),
            err => this.logError(err),
            () => this.finishedGetIndexList('Save')
        );
        this.statusForm = 'Add';
        if(this.id){
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of menuList" [ngClass]="class">
    <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
        <md-checkbox
        [name]="checkboxMenu"
        [checked]="(_checkingList(item,selectedMenu))"
        [indeterminate]="(_checkIsIndeterminate(item,selectedMenu))"
                                            (change)="_onChange(item,$event)"
        [disabled]="true">
        {{item.name}}
        </md-checkbox>
    </label>
</div>
```

`this.spaceMenu`, it is a string variable that holds a value `&#160`. I want to insert it before `<md-checkbox.`

If anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<label ...>
<span [outerHTML]="spaceMenu | safeHtml"></span>
<md-checkbox ...
```

For details about the `safeHtml` pipe see [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)
Not sure whether it is necessary here at all or not.

Comment: function of my code is to make the treeview, TreeView and now I have to do, so I don't use this code again, thanks for the reply.