# Who validates the property?

Tags: angular, angular2-render

I'm trying to find the piece of code that is responsible for property value validation.

For example I have:

```
<h1 [style.color]="myColor">
```

And I bound `myColor` variable with input:

```
<input (input)="myColor = $event.target.value">
```

I expect change of color on input change.
**But!** Change happens only if I have valid color name in `myColor` otherwise it keeps an old value.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2DEx6RJOAxT7PlzMPvP?p=preview) with example.

So my question is "How is responsible of property validation?"
I quickly looked though the source code but did not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser just ignores invalid values.
There is no validation happening except sanitization which removes some security-sensitive values like urls [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)