# Angular 2 modify view html after processing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have below angular 2 code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: 'Waiting on port ',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

As an example I would like to append text "3000" to the template output dynamically. How can this be achieved?

So, final output must be "Waiting on port 3000"

EDIT: I should have been a bit more specific. I was expecting answer something like a response object where I could modify the html before it is sent to "frontend" rendering. So, Angular 2 would process binding all the details in the template and then I get the modify the html.

Comment: I guess it would help a lot if you told us where the port number is coming from

Comment: no, Port number is just an example. I could add any static text

Answer (score 3):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: 'Waiting on port {{port}}',
})
export class AppComponent {
  port:number;
  someMethod() {
    this.port = 3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have added an edit to the question.

Comment: Bindings **only** work when added statically to a template of a component. If you want to add bindings dynamically (from a response from the server or similar) you can create a component dynamically like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: what about simple static text's?

Comment: You can pass static text like shown in my answer. You just need to assign it to a field of a component or service and add a binding to the template as shown in my answer. You can also pass HTML, but Angular bindings just won't work this way. You might need to disable sanitizing for some content like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: This might sound little strange but let say there is "<html><body><div>....</div></body></html>". Now I would like to grab only the <body> and remove others and sent it to render. Will that be possible using Pipes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean. `<body>` is outside Angular. Where do you want to grab it from?

Comment: lets say our component's template or templateurl's content has <html> tags in them

Comment: I'm pretty sure Angular doesn't allow `<html>` tags in templates. Templates need to be valid HTML and `<html>` inside `<body>` is invalid and an Angular component won't work if it's root component is not on the `<body>` or a child of `<body>`. If Angular wouldn't for some reason recognize that `<html>` inside a components template is invalid, then the browser would just remove it when the component is added to the DOM.

Comment: I just tried that and it works! my template content (app.component.html) "<html>
<body>
    <h1>
    listening to server.
    </h1>
</body>
</html>"

Comment: it indeed gives me the output but it appends <html> inside our custom angular selector

Comment: What do you mean with "it works"? Does the DOM contain `<html><body>` twice then, once at the top of the document and once inside the component?

Comment: I'd suggest you completely drop any such attempt and consider an entirely new approach ;-)

Comment: yup I wouldn't use it in production but I am playing around with angular 2 :)

Comment: Seems you enabled `ViewEncapsulation.Native`. That might change the situation a bit. But dynamically modifying the template by any means except bindings and directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: no, component is the same that I have posted in my question. I haven't added ViewEncapsulation either.

Comment: I just saw the `#shadow-root` node in your screenshot. I'm pretty sure that normally (default settings) that wouldn't be there.

Comment: Firefox doesn't have shadow-root but results are same. It indeed outputs html inside html :D Angular 2 is good but I think it has a lot to catch up for things like getting an response writer object like you would in c# :)

Comment: Ok, would have to recherche the spec but actually I'm not that interested, because I don't intend to try that ;-)

Comment: yeah :)
anyways thank you so much for the patience in understanding my problem. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Further to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178505/999248)'s answer, if you wanted the method to fire when the component's initialized you could use [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html) as your method, "called after data-bound properties of a directive are initialized" (from the docs).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: 'Waiting on port {{port}}',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  port:number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.port = 3000;
  };
}
```

`OnInit` must be included in your import.

Comment: If he would unconditionally set the value to `3000` he could use `port:number = 3000;` or just `template: 'Waiting on port 3000',`. This is why I used `someMethod()` because there has to be some "event" that causes the value to be set, but this information was not provided in the question.

Comment: It's a good point, an event or some logic to determine the port would be required. In my instance the `this.port` might point to a promise for example.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have added an edit to the question.