# angular 2 - how embed youtube video

Tags: angular

I got this code

```
 <div *ngIf="topic.video">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="300" height="169" src="topic.video.url" style="border:0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

problem: angular will output `src="localhost://8001"` instead of `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hr4BbdUiTUM"`

What could be wrong here?

UPDATE 2

This is what got after Gunter's answer.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/data';

    @Component({
        template: `
            <div class="subheader">Feed</div>
                <div *ngFor="let topic of topics; let index = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
                    <div *ngIf="topic.type == 'discussion'">
                        <div *ngIf="topic.video">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe src="{{sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(topic.video.url)}}" ></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
    })
    export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(
            private sanitizer:Sanitizer,
            private dataService: DataService
        ) {}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.topics = this.dataService.topics;
        }
    }
```

I still got this error

```
company.ts?ac6a:121 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./CompanyComponent class CompanyComponent - inline template:29:41 caused by: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see
```

Comment: Use the pipe like shown in the answer I linked to in my answer below to tell the Angular sanitizer that it should treat the URL as safe.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the URL from a variable you need to enable binding by using `[]` or `{{}}` (never both at the same time, `{{}}` only works for strings, not for objects or arrays):

```
[src]="topic.video.url"
```

or

```
src="{{topic.video.url}}"
```

If the URL gets removed by the DOM sanitizer, you can use a pipe like shown in [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

```
import { Pipe, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'safeResourceUrl'})
export class SafeResourceUrl {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

```
[src]="topic.video.url | safeResourceUrl"
```

You can also just apply

```
this.myUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.topic.video.url);
```

and bind to this instead

```
[src]="myUrl"
```

but the pipe is more reusable.

Comment: src="{{sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(topic.video.url)}}" will give error, am I using it right?

Comment: @angrykiwi using property binding instead

Comment: Not necessarily, but it's usually not a good idea to bind a function in the view because it gets called every time change detection is run. This can also lead your video to be reloaded continually if the `<video>` tag recognizes it as change every time (had to test myself, but don't really want to know ;-) ).

Comment: Why do you insist on this bad style instead of for example using the pipe?

Comment: I don't, just not sure how to do it.

Comment: I should put the iframe into a component of itself?

Comment: possible to show full example base on what I want to do?

Comment: Hi! I'm having this same problem now. However your fix doesn't work now because `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` is missing from `Sanitizer` now. Mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677276/how-to-correctly-embed-youtube-iframes-into-angular2-view-getting-unsafe-value

Comment: Change `Sanitizer` to `DomSanitizer`