# How to correctly embed youtube iframes into Angular2 view? Getting unsafe value error

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, youtube

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:23:84 caused by: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

#### My homeData model

```
{ id: 1, title: '2017 Super Bowl', graphic: 'https://wikitags.com/images/SuperBowlBanner.png',
  categorycards: [
    {
        type: "video",
        url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Egf5U8xLo8?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0',
        title: "2017 Super Bowl Commercials",
        listings: ["Netflix", "Nintendo", "Intel", "Ford", "Wendy's"]
    },
```

#### The markup: home.component.html

```
<div class="container col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let card of category.categorycards">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="/wiki/entity" *ngIf="card.type == 'image'">
        <div class="image-wrap">
            <img [src]="card.graphic" class="img-responsive" alt="[card.title]" title="[card.title]">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="/wiki/category" *ngIf="card.type == 'video'">
        <div class="image-wrap">
            <iframe title="YouTube video player"
                    class="youtube-player"
                    type="text/html"
                    [src]="card.url" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </a>
```

I found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200287/angular-2-how-embed-youtube-video).

However when I tried to create the saferesourceurl.pipe.ts file got this error:

> Property 'bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl' does not exist on type 'Sanitizer'.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Sanitizer` to `DomSanitizer`.
You get injected the same instance, but the IDE doesn't show any warnings.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting this error :( I'll make a new question and link you first: `Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safeResourceUrl' could not be found ("s="image-wrap">
       <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" [ERROR ->][src]="card.url | safeResourceUrl" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: You need to add the pipe to `declarations: [SafeResourceUrl]` of your module

Comment: Yeah I did that, question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677714/the-pipe-saferesourceurl-could-not-be-found

Comment: I got other error, when video is <embed> from YT. I made safeURL Pipe, added to declaration in module, and I am using ngFor earlier so it goes like [src]="video | safe". PS. I also use DOMSanitizer.
ERROR:  The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled. If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle.