# insert html without using innerHTML angular2

Tags: angular

Seems not safe to use innerHTML, there is another technique to inject or insert HTML from an array?

let's said I've an array with html content, like:

```
        const ItemSections: ItemSection[] = [
            {
                heading: "Lorem",
                SectionHTML: `
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>,
                id: "Lorem"
            },
            {
                heading: "ipsum",
                SectionHTML: `
                    <h3>Ipsum amet</h3>
                    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>,
                id: "ipsum"
            }
        ];
```

**template of component**

```
        <section class="row" *ngFor="let section of lItemSection">
                    <aside class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <h3>{{section.heading}}</h3>
                    </aside><!-- /col -->
                    <aside class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                         <p>{{section.SectionHTML}}</p>
                    </aside><!-- /col -->
        </section>
```

However, the technique above render html tags

if I use the innerHTML works great, like:

```
                        <div [innerHTML]="section.SectionHTML"></div>
```

but exposes the app to XSS security risks!

suggestions??

Comment: Looks like your `SectionHTML` is comming from as data from some service call. Make sure when capturing those data validate it properly before saving it to database. Then you can use innerHTML.

Comment: at the moment is called from the actual component, not from a service call

Comment: That means it is static on component. Then you can easily use innerHTML I belive. Any way your component is in client side. So it does not matter I think.

Answer (score -1):

Angular sanitizes HTML added using `[innerHTML]`. You need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) to get potentially dangerous content into the DOM this way.

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html
- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)