# angular 2 condition inside a href

Tags: angular

I have this line of code

```
<a href="{{banner.url}}"></a>
```

But sometimes url is null. How can I check it for null and then pass url to href?

I've tried this

```
<a href="{{banner.url === null ? javascript:void(0) : banner.url}}"></a>
```

But it throws an error

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{banner.url === null ? javascript:void(0) : banner.url}}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a [href]="banner.url === null ? 'javascript:void(0)' | safeUrl : banner.url"
```

With `safeUrl` being a pipe like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076868/217408

otherwise `javascript:void(0)` probably won't be added for security reasons (not tried myself)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{banner?.url || '#'}}"></a>
```

change `#` with your default URL

Answer (score 0):

Use **ternary operator** in interpolation.

```
<a href="{{banner?.url === null ? 'javascript:void(0)': banner.url }}"></a>
```