# angular-cli : How to use interpolation in a property binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

How is one able to use interpolation within a two-way binding style applied?

`[style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + images/{{image}} + ')'"`

Where the `{{image}}` input interpolation spits out a lot of errors regarding `expected expression` and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url(\'images/' + image + '\')'"
```

You *never* use `[prop]=` together with `{{}}`. Either `[]` or `{{}}

You can also try

```
style.backgroundImage="'url(' + images/{{image}} + ')'"
```

I never tried if style bindings work without `[]`

Comment: Neither seem to work in my case. I get an `ng-reflect-style="unsafe"` in the inspector.

Comment: The `angular` tag is for Angular2, Angular4, ... For Angular 1.x please use the angularjs tag. If your question is actually about Angular2 (4) please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: This is why I have put `angular-cli` in my title. My question concerns Angular2+. I am trying to apply the inputs with interpolation within my Component, directly inside the `*.component` file.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It seems to be a recurring problem on [style.whatever]. Using ngStyle instead seems to fix it.

Comment: @unitario I don't see how this would be related to `ngStyle`. They should have the same behavior.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , this is what I am working with - `[style.background-image]="'url(\'images/browser/' + screenOne + '\')'"` and it is not getting past the errors in the console. The error in this case is `Unexpected token 'images'`

Comment: Did you check the answer I linked to in my first comment above?

Comment: Why would it not be possible. You just need to tell Angular that the URL you want to bind is safe. That's what the linked answer explains.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , the issue here is that `[style.background-image]` should be in plain JS syntax like so -  `[style.backgroundImage]`. This fixes my problem.