# How do I create link tag using interpolation in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I currently am making an app in Ionic 2/Angular 2, and have come across a hurdle I can't quite solve.

To give some insight, I'm getting a bunch of strings from a webservice, where some of the strings could look like this example:

"This is a string with a link: http://www.somelink.com"

I have set up a RegEx to find the link in the strings (if there are any) and convert them to an  tag, as follows:

```
"This is a string with a link: 
<a href="the link from above">the link from above</a>"
```

I want to put this string with the  tag into following html:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of wishes">
    <div ion-item text-wrap style="user-select: text">
       {{item.wish}}
      </div>     
 </ion-item-sliding>
```

item.wish contains the "this is a string....." mentioned above, and I want it to actually create the link so it's clickable, but for some reason it displays the  tag, instead of making it a link. I was expecting the interpolation to parse the HTML tag into a working link instead of just printing the entire tag.

**UPDATE**

In my ts file I have this:

```
urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
      return "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>";
    })
  }
```

A basic method for making this:

```
"This is a string with a link: http://www.somelink.com"
```

into this:

```
 "This is a string with a link: 
    <a href="http://www.somelink.com">http://www.somelink.com</a>"
```

That string is then passed onto the HTML page, via the interpolation, shown above.

So the tag is created in the code, because it has to be dynamic creation of list items, so i cannot set the tag in the HTML. If I created the tag in the HTML like:

```
<a [href]="{{item.wish}}">somelink</a>
```

It would also make the text Next to the link ("This is a string with a link") into a link as well, which is not the intention, only the link should be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a [href]="item.wish">the link from above</a>"
```

Comment: Sadly that is not what I'm looking for, I'll provide some more code, to make the issue more clear, I'll update my initial question, just a sec

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868. You can use `<div [innerHTML]="mySanitizedHtml"></div>`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have solved the problem.

But brings up another question, I have a button on the item, to edit it, when I click it, it takes the wish "This is a string....." and puts it in an input field for edit, before the link worked, it just took the link as a string, but now it takes the tag with it, so when I pull it out of the list again, it'll have:

"This is a string with a link: 
<a href="http://www.somelink.com">http://www.somelink.com</a>"

Is there a some method to convert it back from it's tag state, to a string like: "http://www.somelink.com" so it can be edited?

Comment: Just change it in code and update `mySanitizedHtml`.

Comment: Excuse my many questions, I am still quite new at Typescrip/javascript
It might be really simple, but how do I turn: 
"This is a string with a link: 
<a href="http://somelink.com">http://www.somelink.com</a>"

into this again, so it can be edited: 
"This is a string with a link: http://www.somelink.com"
          '<button ion-button color="primary" *ngIf="ShowEditBtn" 
          (click)="editWish($event, item)">
       <ion-icon name="build"></ion-icon>
       </button>'

I'm passing the before mentioned item, in that button click, but it comes with the tag

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you try to accomplish. Where or how do you want to edit it?

Comment: Okay so, the first thing you helped with, was to generate a list of wishes (a wish list) where some wishes could have links in them. 
Every item on the list has an edit button, where it passes the wish to an edit controller, where it's displayed in a text box for editing. 
With the help you provided, it now passes the wish WITH the <a> tag, so the user will see: 
`"This is a string: <a href="http://www.somelink.com">somelink<a>`
Where they should be seeing:
`This is a string: http://www.somelink.com`

How do i pass the item without tag, or remove the tag when it comes to the controller.

Comment: I don't think I can help you.

Comment: My apologies for vaguely explaining.
I found a solution for the problem, so it works now.
Thanks for the help, and for your time!

Comment: Glad to hear. .