# MdlDialogService HTML in alert results in sanitisation error

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I am using `MdlDialogService` in my angular2 project to alert.

```
openHelpDialog(){

    let result = this.dialogService.alert("<h5>Welcome to Vision Backlog!</h5>");
    result.subscribe( () => console.log('alert closed') );
}
```

What could be the best way to insert big HTML inside alert? This alert will serve for me as a Help File.

**UPDATE**

I created a separate component for Help, it looks like overhead but serves the purpose. However it gives me `WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content` error

```
openHelpDialog(){

    let result = this.dialogService.alert("Test"+ "<help-content></help-content>");

}
```

Comment: You can try to inject `DomSantitzer` and call `let result = this.dialogService.alert(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("Test" + "..."));` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: I already have a pipe created for sanitizing, but in that case I will have to write the HTML in my .ts file of help-content, right?

Comment: Right . . . .   .  .

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing HTML in .ts file, to avoide writing long html syntax inside alert(), I created separate component that will give the HTML to be inserted. If in that component I again have to write this long HTML in .ts file then it is not too pleasant. Isn't there other way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used MdlDialog. If `<help-content>` is a component, you won't be able to pass it as a string. Angular won't create a component instance for HTML created that way, only for HTML added statically to a components template.

Comment: Okay! thanks anyway :)