# Angular 2 sanitizing unsafe style value background-image

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2. when I was trying to set a background image to a div using a URL I encountered the following error:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868