# asp.net core unsafe image to load

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, image-uploading

Hey in my MVC project in wwwroot I have a folder called "Avatars" with some jpg files in it. each user has a link in the db. So for example user with id 1 has a value in table of "https://www.somelink.com/Avatars/1.jpg". The problem is when I load the program my img element looks like this:

```
<img class="image" src="unsafe:www.somelink.com/Avatars/16025.jpg">
```

Why I am getting this "unsafe:" at the beginning of the src link? What does it mean and how can I fix this?

**Update 1:**

So I got asked for the code where I'm emitting my image.

```
<img class="image" [attr.src]="profilePicture" />
```

profilePicture is just loaded value from database and if no value found, no image is loaded, so there is nothing much to show... And yes I am using Angular2..

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to emit the image tag.

Comment: I feel the unsafe is coming from Angular and not ASP.NET Core. Can you try adding http:// or https:// to the URL you get from the DB?

Comment: I think you need to mark it as safe like sown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868