# How to bind the component selector to display dynamic string data in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using angular 4 in my application and I wanted to use a reusable component which helps me to display some information dynamically based on the user. So as a first step I have created component!.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'pageInfo',
  templateUrl: './pageInfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pageInfo.component.scss']
})
export class PageInfoComponent implements OnInit {


  public info: string;
  public manipulatedString: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  stringManipulation(){

    this.manipulatedString = "" // Some sort of manipulation using this.info string value

  }
}
```

Now I will start using `<pageInfo></pageInfo>` tag in some other html pages, while using I want to pass some hard coded string value into **PageInfoComponent** class through Component selector. After getting string value **PageInfoComponent** class will manipulate it and add some sort of styles and the result will be displayed.

**pageInfo.component.html**

```
<div>{{manipulatedString}}</div>
```

So how can I pass string value from component selector to it's class, so that I can display manipulated string with reusable component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

to the template of your `pageInfo` component

or you can pass the string to an input of your `pageInfo` component

```
@Input() manipulatedString:string;
```

and the component displays the string itself

```
<span [innerHTML]="manipulatedString"></span>
```

For this you need to use the `DomSanitizer` to indicate to Angular that it's safe to add HTML tags from this string (your responsibility that it doesn't contain harmful HTML) and use it like

```
<pageInfo [content]="manipulatedString"></pageInfo>
```

You would need to add `<div></div>` in TypeScript,
or

```
<pageInfo [content]="'<div>'+manipulatedString+'</div>'"></pageInfo>
```

Comment: @Zöchbauer Thanks for your answer, it is working fine :).

Comment: I think in <pageInfo/> selector while passing string value  it is not necessary to keep inside <div/> tag, single cots are more than enough.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what exactly you try to accomplish. If you don't want to add the `<pageInfo>` component, then you don't need to, I used it because you mentioned it in your question.

Comment: Yes you are right, but when I tried without <div/> still it is working fine

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question that shows what you tried?

Comment: Now code is not different from the above posted code, I suppose to use `@Input()` and single coted string message inside `<pageInfo/>` tag. If I use any HTML tags with the string value, then I need to sanitize before it reflect on UI.

Comment: Thatßs right, otherwise HTML us stripped from the string. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax

Comment: Small question, Even while passing string value I need to pass HTML content(s), so `DomSanitizer` is good enough to sanitize for the most of the HTML content? or should I also use ` SecurityContext, SafeHtml ` (Sorry I don't no much on this)

Comment: `SafeHtml` pipe is just for convenience, DomSanitizer is enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Input decorator for communication between parent and the child.You can find documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)  .For example

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'pageInfo',
  templateUrl: './pageInfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pageInfo.component.scss']
})
export class PageInfoComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges{


  public info: string;
  public manipulatedString: string;
  @Input() private stringToManipulate:string;

  constructor() {
  }

ngOnChanges (){
     this.manipulatedString=this.stringToManipulate;

 }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  stringManipulation(){

    this.manipulatedString = "" // Some sort of manipulation using this.info string value

  }
}
```

and in the template you can display using

```
<div>{{manipulatedString}}</div>
```

and in the parent component you can use

```
<pageInfo [stringToManipulate]="variable name/'the value of the string you want to send' "></pageInfo>
```

Comment: small correction, @ <pageInfo> tag if we want to pass any string value then it must be inside the single cote I.e.  <pageInfo [stringToManipulate]=" ' Some text ' "></pageInfo>

Answer (score 1):

Günter Zöchbauer answer is amazing and you can follow that. Another way I follow is

call the component from html by binding string to a input variable of the component as below.

```
<pageInfo [manipulatedString]="'the hard coded string value'"></pageInfo>
```

you can get that in your component by declaring it as a input variable

```
@Input() manipulatedString:string;
```

And then you can simply display your string after manipulating in your component class

```
<div>{{manipulatedString}}</div>
```