# Angular4 [innerHTML] ignores returns

Tags: angular

I got json Data that output text with returns:
[image]

Now i try to output it with:

```
<div [innerHTML]="message.content"></div>
```

But the result is this:
[image]

What can i do, that he show the returns?

Comment: returns are ignored by the browser, not by Angular. You either need to wrap in `<pre>...</pre>` or similar, or replace returns with `<br>`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: why don't you use InnerText? .. does you need html??

Comment: Don't program this way. `[innerHTML]` is not designed as a way to construct arbitrary HTML. It's designed for very narrow, specific use cases, where you have data that happens to be pre-formatted in HTML. In any case, newlines are always ignored in HTML. If you want it to work some other way, try CSS properties such as `white-space`.

Comment: Thanks alot @federico scamuzzi! I didnt know that this directive exist! This works very well, thanks again!

Comment: happy to helped you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `[innerHTML]` will render HTML, when you are saying returns i'm assuming you are referring to `\r\n` carriage returns and line feeds. This is not HTML.

What you need to do is pass in HTML for your `\r\n` as for example `<br />`