# angular4 import html file

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I want to save test.svg in component variable 'a' or svgicon.component.html.
So, I create svgicon.component.ts file.
but not working.
what should I do?

svgicon.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { svgs } from './svg/test.svg';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-svgicon',
  templateUrl: './svgicon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./svgicon.component.css']
})
export class SvgiconComponent implements OnInit {
  public a: string = svgs;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

test.svg

`<svg version="1.1" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14">
  <path fill="#D4D4D4" d="M5,0.024c-2.761,0-5,2.269-5,5.069c0,1.139,0.37,2.19,0.996,3.036l-0.02,0.039l2.664,3.856l1.349,1.953 l1.339-1.953l2.62-3.82C9.607,7.345,10,6.265,10,5.093C10,2.293,7.761,0.024,5,0.024z M5,7.024c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2s0.895-2,2-2 s2,0.895,2,2S6.105,7.024,5,7.024z" />
</svg>`

folder directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMMC.png)

Comment: are you sure that `svgs` is there in `test.svg`

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? I can't see anything in your question that indicates how you add the SVG to the DOM.

Comment: `import { svgs } from './svg/test.svg';` is not working. I want to save this html content in variable 'a'.
'test.svg' file must be written in html syntax only.

Comment: Is `test.svg` is a component having template  ?

Comment: test.svg is html file.

Comment: Rohan case 1 is answer for you. still not working better not to import give  http call to `http.get('htmlfile')` add that result to your component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [innerHTML]="a"></div>
```

or (depending on the content of `a`)

```
<svg [innerHTML]="a"></svg>
```

You might need to apply the sanitizer to convince Angular that it's safe to add the content of `a`. For more details see [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

If your component variable `a` contain path of `svg` url like

```
export class SvgiconComponent implements OnInit {
  public a: string = 'test.svg';

}

Then use this path inside your image src to render svg image:

<img [src]='a'/>
```

**Case2**

If your component varibale `a` contain svg template

```
  export class SvgiconComponent implements OnInit {
      public a: string = `<svg version="1.1" width="10" height="14" viewBox="0 0 10 14">
      <path fill="#D4D4D4" d="M5,0.024c-2.761,0-5,2.269-5,5.069c0,1.139,0.37,2.19,0.996,3.036l-0.02,0.039l2.664,3.856l1.349,1.953 l1.339-1.953l2.62-3.82C9.607,7.345,10,6.265,10,5.093C10,2.293,7.761,0.024,5,0.024z M5,7.024c-1.105,0-2-0.895-2-2s0.895-2,2-2 s2,0.895,2,2S6.105,7.024,5,7.024z" />
    </svg>`;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }

In this scenario you need to add this inside your template `(svgicon.component.html)`:

<div [innerHTML]='a'></div>
```