# Angular4: SafeUrl in SafeHtml

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

What I am trying to achieve is a dynamically generated html with some static links in it.

So, in a component, I have an array of objects:

```
 let list = [{
     type: 'container',
     title: 'SIMPLE LIST'
     description: '<ul>
       <li>
         <a href='/some/link#A'>A</a> // or [href] or routerLink+fragment
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href='/some/link#B'>B</a> 
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href='/some/link#C'>C</a>
       </li>
     </ul>'
   }, {
     type: 'container',
     title: 'SIMPLE ICON'
     description: '<mat-icon class="material-icons">launch</mat-icon>'
   }]
```

Then I pass it to a service which sanitize the `description` key via `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` (from `DomSanitzer`):

```
   export class myDynamicBuilder {

     content: Array<object>;         

     constructor(content, sanitizer) {
       content.forEach(each => {
         if (item.hasOwnProperty('description') && typeof item['description'] === 'string') {
           item['description'] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item['description'])
         }
       this.content = content
       })
     }
   }
```

Then in template:

```
<table *ngIf="(items?.content | filterContentBy: 'container').length">  
  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="(items?.content | filterContentBy:'container')">                   
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <b>{{item?.title}}</b>                                                                                 
      </td>
    </tr>                                                                                                      

    <tr>                                                                                                       
      <td colspan="2" class="second-row">                                                                      

        <p *ngIf="item.description" [innerHTML]="item.description"</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</table>
```

Links in `description` field do not work as expected.:

- if `href` is used as attribute a complete reload of the app is triggered (which is very bad)
- if the `routerLink` directive is used the link doesn't work
- if `[href]` is used I get the usual XSS security warning. So, I went back to the docs and I've found the convenient `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` function. I modified the above mentioned service to replace strings after  `[href]` with the output of the `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` and then throw the result in the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` function. Got a very nicely rendered HTML but with a non functional link.

How should I handle this scenario? I am thinking of building some pipes as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) question but not sure if this is the right way to do it. Another idea could be to let my service handle a new key (maybe `links`) of the input object, sanitize via `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` and then inject safe links in the sanitized HTML. Is there any defined way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `[href]="..."` or `routerLink` will be completely ignored by Angular for HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."`. It will be just added to the DOM as is. Using `...TrustUrl` is therefore bogus. Perhaps you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: I forgot to mention that if hardcoding `href` or `routerLink` outside the dynamic portion everything works as expected...

Comment: Right. I forgot to add "or HTML added using `[innerHTML]="..."`"