# How to load an text/html from an URL on Angular 7

Tags: angular, url, angular7

I am using Angular 7. I want to invoke an URL which returns HTML (that basically renders map from a site).

Through the below program, I am able to hit the External Server URL (http://localhost:3344/webappbuilder/apps/8) and it generates a blob (returning text/html).

I want to manipulate the blob and place it on div to display the the html in the form of map.

May I know how I can manipulate the blob and render the results(HTML) as map on Angular 7.

and also let me know:

How can I load an external HTML file (http://localhost:3344/webappbuilder/apps/8/index.html) on my Angular page (Angular 7)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax)

Comment: You could try to import something like cheerio to give you an API for adding the raw html into a variable and using jquery-like syntax to manipulate the "dom". And then you'd need to run that through angular's sanitizer to bypass security so you can inject it into a div on the template.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the value that you get into the [innerHTML] of a div.

In the component code, you need to get the text into a string:

```
htmlTemplate = '<h1>Test Html</h1>';
```

Then, you can bind the innerHTML of an existing component.

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlTemplate"></div>
```

Find the StackBlitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcr1jk

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using innerHTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlTemplate"></div>
```

But you need to sanitize if you are doing this.

> DomSanitizer helps preventing Cross Site Scripting Security bugs (XSS)
>   by sanitizing values to be safe to use in the different DOM contexts.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(html);
  }
}
```

Like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlTemplate | safeHtml"></div>
```

You can get more reference in below link about sanitizing HTML and styles etc.

refer: [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)