# How to make button work with innerHTML in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

When I use innerHTML like this the buttons will not show in the view. The button tags are remove.

inside component

```
const htmldata = '<button>test</button>
```

template

```
<div class="body" [innerHTML]="htmldata"></div>
```

Comment: using this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998831/angular-dynamic-button-implement-in-html/60000023#60000023

Comment: I think you will get the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868