# HTML code is not rendering, just being displayed as plaintext

Tags: javascript, html, angular-material2, angular5, prismjs

I have some HTML, but for some reason it's showing up as plaintext and it's not rendering.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The HTML for this is like so:

```
<div>
  <mat-card>
    <button mat-raised-button>Copy Code to Clipboard</button>
    <mat-card-title>Card with title and footer</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Subtitle</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-content>
      <code>{{muchoCodo}}</code>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
      <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
    <mat-card-footer>
      Card Footer
    </mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>

</div>

{{muchoCodo}}
```

The string data is being rendered as the muchoCodo variable. Here is my Angular code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var Prism;

import 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-handlebars.min.js'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-lua.min.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-generated-code',
  templateUrl: './generated-code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generated-code.component.scss'],
  styles: [`
    mat-card { margin:2em; }
  `]
})
export class GeneratedCodeComponent implements OnInit {

  muchoCodo: string;

  constructor() {

    this.muchoCodo = Prism.highlight(`

    import suman = require('suman');
    const {Test} = suman.init(module);

    Test.create((b, it, before) => {

      it('bahru', t => {

      });

    });


    `, Prism.languages.javascript);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Anybody know how I can get the string to render as HTML?

Comment: What if you change it to `this.muchoCodo = 'testing';`?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Angular2 parse string to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933594/angular2-parse-string-to-html)

Comment: You need to parse the html as using `[innerHTML]='yourValueHere'` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to render the text as HTML, you have to bind to the `innerHTML` property of the desired container element.

```
<mat-card-content>
  <code [innerHTML]="muchoCodo"></code>
</mat-card-content>
```

Keep in mind that this is a potential security issue and you should trust the HTML content you are going to render on the page.